# Folding with a passed function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, fold

I have a function `func` in haskell of the form `func :: (Foldable t, Eq b, Num b) => t b -> b`, this is intended to take a function from a pre-existing main function (i.e. I can't change the input/output pattern), which is a `helper` of the form `helper :: (Eq a,Num a) =>  a -> a -> a`, as well as a list of values, and I want to fold the list with the operation given in the `helper` function.

The full code block is

```
helper :: (Eq a,Num a) =>  a -> a -> a
helper x y  
  | x == 0 && y == 0 = 0
  | x == 0 && y == 1 = 1
  | x == 1 && y == 0 = 1
  | x == 1 && y == 1 = 0

func :: (Foldable t, Eq b, Num b) => t b -> b
func help lst = foldl (help) 0 lst
```

Which gives a compilation error:

```
File.hs:23:23: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘a0 -> b0’
      Expected: b0 -> a0 -> b0
        Actual: t b
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          func :: forall (t :: * -> *) b.
                 (Foldable t, Eq b, Num b) =>
                 t b -> b
        at File.hs:22:1-44
    • In the first argument of ‘foldl’, namely ‘(help)’
      In the expression: foldl (help) 0 lst
      In an equation for ‘func’: func help lst = foldl (help) 0 lst
    • Relevant bindings include
        lst :: t0 a0 (bound at File.hs:23:10)
        help :: t b (bound at File.hs:23:5)
        func :: t b -> b (bound at File.hs:23:1)
```

I honestly have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Can you please share the full code block?

Comment: It seems that your `help` has as signature `(a -> b)`, but it expects `(b -> a -> b)` for `foldl`.

Comment: I've added the full code block in-edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `helper` function here, not a parameter, so you work with:

```
func :: (Foldable t, Eq b, Num b) => t b -> b
func lst = foldl helper 0 last
```

or shorter:

```
func :: (Foldable t, Eq b, Num b) => t b -> b
func = foldl helper 0
```

You can also make use of [**`xor :: Bits a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:xor):

```
import Data.Bits(Bits, xor)

func :: (Foldable t, Bits b, Num b) => t b -> b
func = foldl xor 0
```